# How to add a screen to my game in WP7 XNA?

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna

I've just finished a game in WP7 XNA, I need now to make a main menu screen, highest scores screen, and instructions screen.

I need to know how to add a screen for the main menu, and how to make the game start executing from there.

And how to navigate between these screens.

Thanks.

Comment: How far have you got already? Are you trying t do this in a hybrid SL/XNA app, or a pure XNA one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is introduction to XNA best practices. I would recommend you checking out that sample http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/game_state_management

The sample helped me a lot with understanding how to manage screens, input and menus in my game.